# Want to modify this github code for Q2A

Tags: php

https://github.com/amiyasahu/q2a-email-notification

This plugin send emails for favorite questions I want it for all questions whether it is favorited or not....can anyone tell how can I do that? what I have to changed in this code?

Answer (score 0):

As you try to make the File Upload controls as 
**Tags - use hyphens to combine words:**. For this, you have to recode the upload plugin or there also a way to redesign the modal popup.
But there some restriction with this plugin to do so because all the functionality ie *Description* and *Image URL* can't depreciate from your code.